# Swift FullName Array Sort

Tags: arrays, swift

What's the best way to sort an optional String Array of "full names"

**UPDATED: So sorry .. I forgot the most important point. Needs to be sorted in Last Name, First Name order, and single names, nil's at the top**

```
let unordered:[String?] = [
"Zach Appletree",
"Nancy Crabtree",
"Bill",
nil,
"Bonny Appletree",
"Zach Johnson",
"Paul Brandon"
]

let sortedArray = unordered.sorted(by: { } )
```

Comment: What is your desired output? Search by alphabetical last name? Alphabetical first name? Where do the `nil` items go? Do they get filtered out or do they go on the beginning/end?

Comment: If your full name can also be just first name (like you specified), and possibly "LastName FirstName" (e.g. "Liu Jianguo", where Liu is the last name) then you can only treat them as just *strings*, and sort alphabetically, as you cannot assume anything. The only question is if you want to live nils in our out (i.e. to use `compactMap or not).

Comment: try something like this: `let sortedArray = unordered.compactMap{$0}.sorted(by: { $0 < $1})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PersonNameComponents` is not `Comparable` unless you define conformance yourself.

E.g.

```swift
unordered
  .lazy
  .compactMap { $0.flatMap(PersonNameComponentsFormatter().personNameComponents) }
  .sorted()
```

```swift
extension PersonNameComponents: Comparable {
  public static func < (components0: Self, components1: Self) -> Bool {
    var fallback: Bool {
      [\PersonNameComponents.givenName, \.middleName].contains {
        Optional(components0[keyPath: $0], components1[keyPath: $0])
          .map { $0.lowercased().isLessThan($1.lowercased(), whenEqual: false) }
        ?? false
      }
    }
    
    switch (
      components0.givenName?.lowercased(), components0.familyName?.lowercased(),
      components1.givenName?.lowercased(), components1.familyName?.lowercased()
    ) {
    case let (
      _, familyName0?,
      _, familyName1?
    ):
      return familyName0.isLessThan(familyName1, whenEqual: fallback)
    case (
      _, let familyName0?,
      let givenName1?, nil
    ):
      return familyName0.isLessThan(givenName1, whenEqual: fallback)
    case (
      let givenName0?, nil,
      _, let familyName1?
    ):
      return givenName0.isLessThan(familyName1, whenEqual: fallback)
    default:
      return fallback
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Comparable {
  /// Like `<`, but with a default for the case when `==` evaluates to `true`.
  func isLessThan(
    _ comparable: Self,
    whenEqual default: @autoclosure () -> Bool
  ) -> Bool {
    self == comparable
    ? `default`()
    : self < comparable
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Exchange two optionals for a single optional tuple.
  /// - Returns: `nil` if either tuple element is `nil`.
  init<Wrapped0, Wrapped1>(_ optional0: Wrapped0?, _ optional1: Wrapped1?)
  where Wrapped == (Wrapped0, Wrapped1) {
    self = .init((optional0, optional1))
  }

  /// Exchange two optionals for a single optional tuple.
  /// - Returns: `nil` if either tuple element is `nil`.
  init<Wrapped0, Wrapped1>(_ optionals: (Wrapped0?, Wrapped1?))
  where Wrapped == (Wrapped0, Wrapped1) {
    switch optionals {
    case let (wrapped0?, wrapped1?):
      self = (wrapped0, wrapped1)
    default:
      self = nil
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: WOW... would have never come up with that... Nice!

Comment: how complex does this become if the personname/fullname is inside of a struct?

So an array of:

struct Passengers {
    var id: String
    var fullName: String?
    var state: String
}

Comment: I don't know how to measure what you're asking. But I also don't know why you wouldn't be storing `nameComponents: PersonNameComponents` instead of `fullName: String`.

Comment: unfortunatly is data from a Realm DB and it comes that way from the DB. This is an existing struct and would need to change how fullname is pulled.  Can do that just didnt' now how it changes the flatmap because its a struct being returned vs PersonNameComponents.  If I had it my way I would have just included FirstName, LastName as a part of the struct

Comment: Thanks, Jessy, I changed the internal sort to use PersonNameComponets and the struct array is now sorted!  Again Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a compactMap(_:)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap

```
let unordered:[String?] = [
        "Zach Appletree",
        "Nancy Crabtree",
        "Bill",
        nil,
        "Bonny Appletree",
        "Zach Johnson",
        "Paul Brandon"
        ]
        
let sortedArray = unordered.compactMap { $0 }.sorted()
print(sortedArray)
```